# Why do I get duplicates into my multithreaded processed list, using pandas and requests in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, concurrent.futures

EDIT2: Solved! Thanks to Michael Butscher's comment, I made a shallow copy of `req_params` by renaming the argument `req_params` to `req_params_arg` and then adding `req_params = req_params_arg.copy()` in `get_assets_api_for_range()`.

The variable was shared between the threads, so copying before use solved the problem.

EDIT: It seems that "python requests" doesn't like being called simultaneously by several threads, I activated debug mode and I can see that the requests sent to the API are sometimes equal (same range asked) which leads to the duplicates. Weird behavior... Do you think I need to use aiohttp or asyncio??

I'm struggling with the concurrent.futures module in order to fetch a large volume of data from an API.
The API I'm using is limiting results to 100 results per page, then I'm calling it multiple times in order to get all the data.

To accelerate the process I tried to use multithreading (ThreadPoolExecutor) with a maximum of 10 threads.
It works fine and it's very quick but the results are different each time... Sometimes I get duplicates, sometimes not.

It seems not to be thread-safe somewhere but I cannot figure out where... Maybe it is hidden into the functions that uses pandas behind?

I tried to echo the no of pages it's getting and it's pretty correct (not in order but normal):

```
Fetching 300-400
Fetching 700-800
Fetching 800-900
Fetching 500-600
Fetching 400-500
Fetching 0-100
Fetching 200-300
Fetching 100-200
Fetching 900-1000
Fetching 600-700
Fetching 1100-1159
Fetching 1000-1100
```

Another weird behavior is here: when I put the line `req_sess = authenticate()` after the line `print("Fetching {}".format(req_params['range']))` in `get_assets_api_for_range` function, only one page (the last I believe) is fetched multiple times.

Thanks for your help!!

Here is my code (I removed some parts, I should be enough I think), the main function called is `get_assets_from_api_in_df()`:

```
from functools import partial
import pandas as pd
import requests
import concurrent.futures as cfu


def get_assets_api_for_range(range_to_fetch, req_params):
    req_sess = authenticate()

    req_params.update({'range': range_to_fetch})
    print("Fetching {}".format(req_params['range']))

    r = req_sess.get(url=auth_config['endpoint_url'] + '/assets',
                     params=req_params)

    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise ConnectionError("API Get assets error: {}".format(r))

    json_response = r.json()

    # This function in return, processes the list into a dataframe
    return process_get_assets_from_api_in_df(json_response["asset_list"])


def get_assets_from_api_in_df() -> pd.DataFrame:
    GET_NB_MAX = 100

    # First, fetch 1 value to get nb to fetch
    req_sess = authenticate()
    r = req_sess.get(url=auth_config['endpoint_url'] + '/assets',
                     params={'range': '0-1'})
    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise ConnectionError("API Get assets error: {}".format(r))

    json_response = r.json()
    nb_to_fetch_total = json_response['total']
    print("Nb to fetch: {}".format(nb_to_fetch_total))

    # Building a queue of ranges to fetch
    ranges_to_fetch_queue = []
    for nb in range(0, nb_to_fetch_total, GET_NB_MAX):
        if nb + GET_NB_MAX < nb_to_fetch_total:
            range_str = str(nb) + '-' + str(nb + GET_NB_MAX)
        else:
            range_str = str(nb) + '-' + str(nb_to_fetch_total)
        ranges_to_fetch_queue.append(range_str)

    params = {

    }

    func_to_call = partial(get_assets_api_for_range,
                           req_params=params)

    with cfu.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        result = list(executor.map(func_to_call, ranges_to_fetch_queue))

    print("Fetch finished, merging data...")

    return pd.concat(result, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: For me it looks like an (intended?) behavior of the API to not return the results in the same order on different calls. You could set the "max_workers" to 1 to disable multithreading and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I set "max_workers" to 1, the sequence is in order and no duplicates are found in the result. I tried several times without any errors. I also tested the API on postman and the results are ok... Switching to max_workers = 5 make the duplicates come back.. sometimes...

Comment: In "get_assets_api_for_range" the dictionary "req_params" seems to be shared between the threads. Try to create a (shallow) copy at the beginning of the function and then modify and use only the copy for retrieving of data.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, it solved the problem. I just edited the post.